# Fill of a Rectangle with SolidColorBrush does not work

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have problems assigning a `SolidColorBrush` to the `Fill` property of a `Rectangle` object in WP7.

```
// sets the clock style (1-green, 2-blue, 3-red)
private void SetClockStyle(Int32 style)
{
    Color blue = new Color() { R = 0, G = 63, B = 216 };
    Color green = new Color() { R = 79, G = 255, B = 0 };
    Color red = new Color() { R = 255, G = 39, B = 0 };

    switch (style)
    {
        case 1:
            Fill(green);
            break;
        case 2:
            Fill(blue);
            break;
        case 3:
            Fill(red);
            break;
        default: 
            break;
    }
}

// sets a color
private void Fill(Color color)
{
    foreach (Rectangle rect in this.GetRectangles())
    {
        rect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(color);
    }

    foreach (Rectangle rect in this.GetPoints())
    {
        rect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(color);
    }
}
```

When I call `SetClockStyle(2)` the program flow is fine, the correct parts are executed. But the rectangles have no filling (the background color of the grid is displayed). I tried settings the `Fill.Opacity` property but that did not change anything. I can't see where the problem is. Setting the `Fill` property via XAML works, but the dynamic approach at run time does not.

How do I assign a specific color to the `Fill` property of a `Rectangle` object?

Comment: Is the GetRectangles method really correctly implemented?

Comment: yes, by default the fill is set to white in XAML and after calling the methods the fill is empty and not white so the GetRectangles works fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it. The problem is the Default value of the alpha channel, which is set to be transparent. Use something like this (notice the added A value):

```
Color red = new Color() { R = 255, G = 39, B = 0, A = 255 };
```

Now the alpha channel is set to 255, which means a non-transparent solid color.